# iOS - custom keyboard on alert view textbox

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, keyboard, uitextfield, uialertview

I have a custom keyboard in my app that at one point needs to be used to input text in to a textfield that is on an alert view, which I have working, using the uitextfield.inputView, but the problem is that the alert view removes the keyboard from the main view, and sets the keyboard's superview property to nil making it unusable unless you restart the app, my question is, what is the best way to preserve the keyboard, so it can be used afterwards, or is just reloading the view controller from the storyboard a good/viable option?

**EDIT:** I have tried retaining the keyboard and re-adding it to the subview, copying the frame and setting that, everything, but it is still not working, is simply reloading the view controller from the storyboard a good idea? or is that to expensive?

Comment: can you show a screenshot

Comment: @meda, there is not really anything to show, the keyboard works, it works on the alert, then from the logs I can see that it has no superview.

Comment: Retain your keyboard and reset it's superview after the alert view is dismissed. If that doesn't answer your question, please show some code.

Comment: @MarcusAdams what do you mean 'reset my superview'?

Comment: @AriPorad, assign it with `addSubview:`, like `[mySuperView addSubview:myKeyboardView];`.

Comment: @AriPorad you want to get help without showing screen shot or code?

Comment: @meda can you be a little more specific on what you would like me to post, I dont really know what would be helpful for you.

Comment: @MarcusAdams what kind of code would you like to see, i am happy to provide it.